# Why is cv2.projectPoints not behaving as I expect?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have a 3D world that I am trying to map to a 2D view using cv2.projectPoints, but it is not acting as I expect. My grasp of opencv, numpy and matrix ops is weak, so I must be making a wrong assumption somewhere. This code:

```
src = np.ones((6, 3))
src[:,1] = 2
src[:,2] = range(6) # source points
rvec = np.array([0,0,0], np.float) # rotation vector
tvec = np.array([0,0,0], np.float) # translation vector
fx = fy = 1.0
cx = cy = 0.0
cameraMatrix = np.array([[fx,0,cx],[0,fy,cy],[0,0,1]])
result = cv2.projectPoints(src, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix, None)
for n in range(len(src)):
    print src[n], '==>', result[0][n]
```

generates this output:

```
[ 1.  2.  0.] ==> [[ 1.  2.]]
[ 1.  2.  1.] ==> [[ 1.  2.]]
[ 1.  2.  2.] ==> [[ 0.5  1. ]]
[ 1.  2.  3.] ==> [[ 0.33333333  0.66666667]]
[ 1.  2.  4.] ==> [[ 0.25  0.5 ]]
[ 1.  2.  5.] ==> [[ 0.2  0.4]]
```

The x- and y-values are being divided by the z-value?! I thought that as I am applying no transformations with rvec and tvec that the output should match the [x,y] values of src.

Comment: This is the correct behavior.  As the src points move further away from the camera pin-hole, they get projected to image points closer to the origin.  Objects further away look smaller in the image.  In other words, the object size scales inverse to the distance.  The equation for the image points (x',y') from the src points (x,y,z)  is written in the documentation at this url  [openCV doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html)

Answer (score 5):

For *no operation* the rotation matrix should be an identity

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

edit:
It's a very simple function to write yourself.

```
foreach input 3dpoint xyz
  3dpoint tmp = cameraintrinsic(3x3) * rotationvect(1x3) * xyz(3x1) + cameraintrinsic(3x3)*translation(3,1)
  2dpoint screen = tmp.x/tmp.z, tmp.y / tmp.z
```

The /tmp.z is because the result is returned in homogeneous coords = essentially 2d coords with a scaling factor.

Comment: Tried that, same results :-( I was using the output of [Rodrigues](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) which gives [0,0,0] for input np.identity(3)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but as you suspected, your interpretation is faulty. The function OpenCV::projectPoints() performs not only a rotation and translation but also an inverse z-distance scaling.

Note that the geometry assumption is that the camera is located at z=0 and pointed along the z-axis.  Consider that at some distance Z from the camera, the field-of-view (i.e. width of the image) is Fx,Fy.  You might measure both Z and F in meters, for example, but is can be in any distance units. You also know the number of pixels in the image are ncols along X-direction and nrows along Y-direction.  Next consider the 3D point in space (x,y,z) you want to project where z is not zero.   The image coordinates are as follows:

```
u= x * ncols/Fx * Z/z
v= y * nrows/Fy * Z/z
```

from this you can see that `fx= ncols/Fx*Z and fx=nrows/Fy*Z`